# how to replace HTML with jQuery but keep event bindings

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is more a strategic question than a specific one, but I think it's precisely asked so here goes:

let's say I have a page or ap that has 3 separate sections.  A change on part of the form sends an ajax post to the server, and this requires a change in section two.  I want to send back the re-processed HTML output of section 2, and have this replace the original state of section 2

but, section 2 has many elements that have change, click, drag etc. bindings - and from experience when I do a html replace, I lose all my bindings.

HOWEVER, this leaves me with rewriting certain things in many of the elements in section 2 individually so as not to lose the bindings.

I *KNOW* there's an easier approach to this, seems like a common problem.  Can anyone provide me with the "aha" part of this question, and perhaps a few examples or links?  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Does the element classname or id changes after replace?

Comment: Since it is a dynamic section, for event bindings you can use event propagation with `$.on` but the problem is widgets like `draggable` which you talked about. ASAIK there is no way other than to re-initialize those widgets on the newly added dom elements

Comment: what is it in the "re-processed HTML output" that you want to keep?  If it's purely the same DOM but different content then you could parse through it, updating the contents of the section.

Comment: the $.on() suggestion given below seems the best answer.  I had seen that but as a immature JS programmer, hadn't understood that this applies to this situation.  gillyspy, the purpose of this is to keep the process of reloading page sections as simple as possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to divide the problem into two sections

**Handling events**
This can be done using event delegation using [$.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/). ie instead of registering events on the element you register on a parent which will not be removed
Ex:

```
$('.container').on('click', 'a', function(){
    //do something
})
```

**Handling widgets like draggable**
Here I think you are out of luck because I don't see any other way than to reinitialize those widgets once the new dom elements are added
Ex:

```
var ct = $('.container').html('');
ct.find('li').draggable({})
```

Comment: I have to confess, I didn't even HAVE anything yet on draggable! :)  I have a talent for mentioning things like that, so as soon as draggable events come up, I will remember that.  Meanwhile i'll do some studying of $.on() - thanks

Answer (score 7):

You could use [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), so you don't have to re-bind.

Answer (score 0):

From [this ticket](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13400)

> In case anyone arrives here as I did looking for a quick alternative to replaceWith() that keeps attached events, it can be done using a combination of existing functions in the current API:

this:

```
old.replaceWith( new );
```

can be changed to:

```
old.before( new ).detach();
```

> Both return a handle to the removed element, so depending on the use case it should be pretty simple to change.